# Problem with the word 'machine' in the definition of machine learning by Mitchell in the book "Machine Learning"

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

The definition : A computer program is said to learn from experience E with respect to some  task T and performance measure P, if its performance at task T, as measured by P, improves with experience E.

Here, we talk about what it means for a program to learn rather than a machine, and a program and a machine aren't equivalent so how can we use this as a definition of machine learning when its a definition of program learning.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to cross validated. This question is likely more appropriate for the [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com), [The AI SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com), or the [Theoretical Computer Science SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com). The short answer to your question is: Programs are always run on machines, and in the abstract, every program or algorithm corresponds to a Turing machine - which is a highly abstract model of how computers work in general. Hence conflating "Machine Learning", "Algorithmic Learning", "Program Learning", etc... makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia, a computer program is a set of instructions used to control the behavior of a machine.

In my not philosophically trained opinion, the same way that we don't make a distinction between a human learning and a human's brain learning we don't make a distinction between a program learning vs a machine learning.